# Is it possible to create a zip file from a folder stored at remote location using SFTP?

Tags: zip, sftp

Basically I wanted to copy a folder from remote location to local machine using SFTP. Since SFTP is a file transfer protocol, copying a folder is not possible. So I am thinking to first zip the folder and then copy the zip file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the SFTP server, actually.

Some servers allow you to execute your own server-side scripts when certain events occur; you could, therefore, write a server-side script that zips up the uploaded files and then copies the zip archive somewhere else, when a successful file transfer session occurs.

If, instead, you don't want to zip anything and you just want to copy/move the files somewhere else, please, keep in mind that the SFTP protocol actually does have a command for that (unlike the FTP protocol). As specified in the [SFTP Extension draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00#section-6), in fact, you can use the following structure to tell the SFTP server to copy a remote file somewhere else on the server:

```
byte   SSH_FXP_EXTENDED
uint32 request-id
string "copy-file"
string source-file
string destination-file
bool   overwrite-destination
```

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. SFTP is only to transfer files (also listing files and simple modification), but to compress file, you need to run external application on the server (`zip`), which is out of the scope of SFTP protocol. To do this, you would need `ssh` as a secure shell.